# XDS gui installation - no route to host

Tags: software-installation, connection, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install XDS on Linux Subsystem for Windows following guide in this [document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343473161_Installation_of_XDS_XDSGUI_XDSSTAT_XDSCC12_and_XDSViewer_packages_in_Windows_10_Subsystem_for_LinuxWSL). So far I've successfully install xds package (step #3). I want to install XDS-Viewer etc as well (step #4) however down to the step iii, I encountered this error

```
--2021-03-04 21:12:11--  ftp://strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de/pub/linux_bin/
  (try: 5) => ‘.listing’

Connecting to strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de (strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de)|134.34.128.100|:21... failed: No route to host.

Resolving strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de (strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de)... 134.34.128.100

Connecting to strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de (strucbio.biologie.uni-konstanz.de)|134.34.128.100|:21... failed: No route to host.

chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink 'xds-viewer'

chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink 'xdsviewer'

chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink 'xscalecc12'

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'xscalecc12': File exists

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'xdsviewer': File exists

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'xds-viewer': File exists

rm: cannot remove 'H5ToXds': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove 'README.*': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove 'dectris-neggia.so': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove 'durin-plugin.so': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove 'xds-zcbf.so': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove 'xdsgui_qt5': No such file or directory

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'xxdiff': File exists

check Unix tools that generate_XDS.INP needs -

python not found

h5dump not found

all done
```

[noroutetohost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4JR.jpg)

I have tried to ping the ip and got response, knowing that I've been successful in previous step I don't think the server is the problem. I have tried to open firewall ports in windows 10 (create new inbound rule for port 21), turned off windows firewall, disable kaspersky, use ufw command, all with no success.
Can I get some help here please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: I do, and I have turned it off. When it's on my connection will be closed automatically.